# Is it possible to change the display of words into symbols in Vim?

Tags: vim, emacs, font-lock

I recently ran across a [post](http://blog.jayfields.com/2013/06/coding-increase-your-reading-and.html) on Jay Fields' blog, in which Jay uses emacs' font-lock mode to change the display of words into symbols.

[image: before]
[image: after]

Is there any way to do this in Vim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Vim's *conceal* feature replaces matches with a single replacement character (or none at all). This is integrated into syntax highlighting, see `:help :syn-conceal`.

For example, the built-in *Tex* filetype uses this to display special sequences directly as Greek characters etc.; see `:help tex-conceal`.  The implementation is in `runtime/syntax/tex.vim` in the standard vim distribution.

Comment: Fantastic! Going to have to look into this.